# Trigonometry- cos and sec

Tags: trigonometry

Is $\cos^2 (x)$ the same as $1/\sec ^2 (x)$ ?

I wasn't sure because $\cos$ is the same as $1/\sec$.

thank you!

Comment: $\cos^2 x = \frac{1}{\sec^2 x}$

Comment: They are the same as long as $x\not= (2n+1)\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ in which case $\sec x$ isn't defined.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much for the details! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. 
$$\begin{align}cos^2 (x) &= \left( cos(x) \right)^2 \\
& = \left( \frac{1}{sec(x)} \right)^2 \\
& = \frac{1}{\left(sec(x) \right)^2} \\
& = \frac{1}{sec^2(x)}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer! :)